# SOAP Web Service on ASP.NET - Multiple Connection - Static Values - XMLRPC API

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap, asmx, xml-rpc

Have a SOAP Web Service that encapsulates calls to a 3rd party API... so our application can simply call my service and then my service handles all the various calls to the API.  Works just fine.

However, we've hit a problem where the API we're connecting to allows a max of 10 connections at any given time for a given set of credentials.

Connections at most take a couple of seconds to process, but when we go live, we could in theory have users that max out this.  So we've created multiple accounts (5) to the API giving us 50 connections across the 5 users.

How does ASP.NET handle connections to the Web service?  I know it works asynchronously, but does it spawn multiple instances of my class or reuse the same class.  Will variables persist across instances (i.e  Will static variables work)?

What I need to do is if a call to the API fails on Client1, rollover to Client2 (or Clients[0], Clients[1]) etc...  Sadly I have no way to detect if a given Client is out of connections at any given moment.  I could poll it with a test call, but that would take time and be no guarantee the the client has a connection available when I make the call.

The API I'm calling is via XMLRPC Proxy class (CookComputing).  Is the "connection" made when the Client is created or when the call is made, passing along the credentials?

```
public static IVoicestar GetClient(string userID, string password)
{
    IVoicestar client = XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<IVoicestar>();
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userID, password);
    return client;
}
```

Seems from this that the credentials simply "ride along" until I make a call via Client.MethodCall() and then the connection is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ASP.NET Web Services (asmx) then it would spawn a new instance of your web service class for each request. In case WCF based web services, you can control the instancing /concurrency using attributes/configuartion (see this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193.aspx)) - you have three instancing modes possible - per call, per session and singleton.

Irrespective of what you are using, you can always implement your own pooling mechanism to pool your API connection. You already have a factory method to get the API client - just put call to pooling layer within method.

Comment: But how can I determine if I NEED another client vs. the connection/credentials I already have?

Comment: @pieklk, sorry for responding late (I was out of station). Essentially, pooling mechanism generally have threshold i.e. max connections possible. In your case, your pool design will be a bit complex because you wanted to have multiple credentials as well as. So your design has to see if max connection threshold for a credential is exhausted or not. If not then create connection for that credential. If yes then move to next credential. If you don't have any left then wait till one get available. continued in next comment...

Comment: a bit simple to implement approach will be to create a pool of all available slots (no of credentials x no of max connections per credentials). Assign a slot when a request is made for connection, mark the slot as "filled" (and create actual API client etc). Whenever, you are done with the connection, inform your pooling layer and it would again mark the slot as free. You can put this logic into close/dispose of your API client (by wrapping it or if its partial class then adding logic to it).

Answer (score -1):

Normally Windows XP and Windows 7 have a limit of 10 concurrent TCP/IP connections. Maybe that's it. Be sure to work in a windows server version.

Comment: -1: the OP said "the API we're connecting to allows a max of 10 connections at any given time for a given set of credentials."